# Difference between addSubview and insertSubview in UIView class

Tags: iphone, uiview, uikit, subview, addsubview

What is the difference between `addSubview` and `insertSubView` methods when a view is added programmatically?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The only difference is in where the view is added:  whether it is the frontmost view (`addSubview:`), or it is before the 5th subview, (`insertSubview:atIndex:`) or if it is immediately behind another subview (`insertSubview:aboveSubview:`).

Answer (score 47):

Using `insertSubView:` you can specify the index, which determines z-order of views. A view with a higher index lies above those with lower indices.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to is there specific difference in uses of these two functions

Comment: Aside from the specific difference I described in my answer, there is none.

Answer (score 29):

I don't think there is a difference. `addSubview:` is simple a convenient method for

```
[view insertSubview:aView atIndex:[view.subviews count]]
```

Answer (score -1):

1.addSubview  add subview in array then add in View'slayer

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    [_subviews addObject:subview];
    [_layer addSublayer:subview.layer];
}
```

}

2.While insertSubview add your view as subview then call 
`[_layer insertSublayer:subview.layer atIndex:index];`

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)subview atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
  [self addSubview:subview];
  [_layer insertSublayer:subview.layer atIndex:index];
}
```